# PtDistWithin() with Geometry from query

Tags: python, spatialite, sqlite

I'm trying to run two Spatialite queries in Python — the first one picks a single point from a table, and the second tries to find all points that are within a given distance of it. So my queries look like:

```
select geometry from points where point_id = 1
```

and

```
select count(*) from points where 
PtDistWithin(points.geometry, <geometry from first query>, 100)
```

I'm stuck on how to inject the geometry that I selected in the first query into the second one. If I drop it in as-is it says cannot concatenate string and buffer objects. I tried selecting it `AsText()` and there are no errors, but the count is always 0 (there should definitely be matches within 100 meters). Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to combine your two queries into one, known as a nested query. I'm not a Spatialite user, but I think the syntax would be:

```
 select count(*) from points where 
 PtDistWithin(points.geometry, (select geometry from points where point_id = 1), 100)`
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - I just had to wrap the subquery in plain parentheses. If you want to edit that I'll accept :)

Comment: @Mapbert Sure thing. I wasn't sure about the IN part, since that's typically used with lists/addressing values from a field, but I didn't have a quick way of testing.